# iphone - stuff inside alertview

Tags: iphone

I have a part on my app that I show the users, the files they have created and have stored inside the app's directory. I want to allow the users to rename the files.

I am wondering of doing this:

1. The user selects a file
2. The user taps on the RENAME button.
3. An alertview pops showing the old name and having a textview where the user can type the new name.

My question is: is this blessed by Apple? This sounds like a hack to the alertview.

Will the app be approved?

I googled around and I saw mixed opinions about that.

thanks

Comment: It's not blessed. Dumpster-diving in the view hierarchy of standard controls is a grey area that you don't want to get into, because (a) you might get rejected for it and (b) even if you don't those internal structures change, often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I think the correct HIG-happy UI would be a UITableView with the list of of files. The user taps and Edit button and the page rows become editable, allowing you to delete a row/file (with a verification alert) and a disclosure arrow that pushes a detail view where you can change the name.

An alternative, though not HIG-friendly, is displaying the file name in a UITextField where the **borderStyle** set to `UITextBorderStyleNone` and the **enabled** set to `NO`. When the user taps the Rename button you change the **borderStyle** to `UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect` and **enabled** set to `YES`, setting the firstResponder to the text field so the cursor is flashing inside the textField. You'd need **OK** and **Cancel** buttons.

Or you could add a text field to the UIAlertView, also against the HIG but perhaps better.

Comment: Thanks. I will go with this and make everyone happy. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the property alertViewStyle was available when you make this question but searching to resolve this problem for me, I found that setting this property with UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is in iPhone sdk alertBox, alertBox can have the textField in which you rename the file.

check this [link](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/undocumented/alert-with-textfields.html)

for making such kind of stuff. No problem in accepting your app

Comment: Actually the linked article shows an example that uses an undocumented API call. That's guaranteed to get your app rejected. You might get away with simply adding UITextViews as subviews to the UIAlertView, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could either subclass UIAletView and add your own initWithTitle:message:...etc. method, as outlined in [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/alert-view-with-prompt.html) tutorial, or use the undocumented `[alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:nil];` method, which is easier but may cause Apple to reject your app.