# Placing textfield in Actionsheet

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to place a text field in Actionsheet? I try this code:

```
UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UITextField *pickerView_freq_payment = [[UITextField alloc] init];

    [menu addSubview:pickerView_freq_payment];
    [menu showInView:self.view];   
    [menu sendSubviewToBack:pickerView_freq_payment];     
    [menu setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 300)];

    CGRect pickerRect = pickerView_freq_payment.bounds;

    pickerView_freq_payment.bounds = pickerRect;

    [pickerView_freq_payment release];
    [menu release];
```

but it doesn't show any text field. I found information on displaying buttons in Actionsheet, but I need to place text fields instead of buttons.

How can I do this? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Displaying text field in action sheet is not a good idea it seems - it will likely become obscured by keyboard when gets focus...

Comment: can u pls suggest alternate way to place text fields in pop up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont need to do this,

You need to implement alert with textfields for change password purpose check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436672/iphone-stuff-inside-alertview/4436706#4436706)

Comment: @Iphone_bharat,ok i delete my comment.this is fine for you.

Comment: hey I dint ask u to delete ur comment , it was fun someone asking for an upvote on his answer, i instead  upvoted the comment ..

Comment: ok great, thanx for your upvote.so you agree with this i am a funny guy.

Comment: hey man .. r u really getting furious .. my intention was not that .. anyways I think we shouldn't pollute this thread anymore .. I accept that maybe I started polluting ,.. but we should stop here

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend against this. `UIActionSheet` has a very specific purpose on the iPhone, and adding text fields to it probably goes against Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.

Could you tell us why you need a text field? This way, we could suggest a more appropriate construct, like a modal view controller.

Comment: For the change password,new password, confirm password

Comment: A "Change Password" screen (which requires two or three text fields) should definitely be done in a modal view controller, not a UITextField. Apple's documentation has an awesome explanation of their purpose at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1